# How to Access Methods through a Class that creates object of another Class?

Tags: php, inheritance

i have a class named **Model**

```
<?php
class Model {
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database(DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    }
}
```

i want to access methods from the class object this construct is instantiating it is from a class named **database** and it has methods like insert using PDO
the error indicates that the class **Model** does not include methods from the **Database** class
i dont understand how to access methods through the model class that exist in the database class

```
$db = new Model();
$db->insert('app', 'asdfsdf');

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model::insert()
```

Comment: Well, technically it is `$db->db->insert`. Practically, your architecture is already broken (yep, just those 3 lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're instantiating the `Database` class, it is a *property* of the `Model` class. So it is accessed like this:

```
$model->db->insert('app', 'asdfsdf');
```

You should also make sure the `$db` property is declared as `public` if you want to access it that way:

```
<?php
class Model {
    public $db;
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database(DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    }
}
```